# VBA Loop stopping entire function

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having a little issue some VBA that I've pieced together from various sources (including here!) Basically I'm trying to loop through a list of customer accounts inputted into a list of cells and uses InStr to tell me whether or not keywords show up in their account history. So far it works great for one account number but when I've tried to create a loop to go through a list of accounts the function seems to just stop at the beginning of the loop. Here's the VBA...

```
Dim rowData As Long
Dim lastRow As Integer

lastRow = Cells(10000, 7).End(xlUp).Row
rowData = 7

For x = rowData To lastRow

With IE
    .Visible = True
    .navigate my_url2
End With

Do Until Not IE.Busy And IE.readyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop

IE.Document.all("acct").Value = Me.Cells(x, 3).Value
IE.Document.all("Lookup").Click

Do Until Not IE.Busy And IE.readyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop

IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(0).contentWindow.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")(1).Click
'clicks button to open history

Do Until Not IE.Busy And IE.readyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop

With IE
    .Visible = True
    .navigate my_url4
End With

Do Until Not IE.Busy And IE.readyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop

promo = IE.Document.all

If InStr(promo.innerText, Range("E5").Value) = 0 Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("C10") = "No"
Else
    ActiveSheet.Range("C10") = "Yes"
End If

Next x
```

I'm definitely not the best when it comes to the looping function but I was hoping maybe there's just something simple I'm missing here. Any help would very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What is the value of `lastRow`?  Put a breakpoint on the `For x` line and see - if `lastRow < rowData`, the loop will never run.  I see you reference columns 3, 5, and 7 in the code --- do all those columns have the same number of rows?

Comment: As well as the suggestion by @cxw (which will probably show the reason why your code isn't running), your lines referring to `ActiveSheet.Range("C10")` will probably need to be changed to `ActiveSheet.Range("C" & x)` (unless you really want to always write to cell C10), but that worries me because you are using `Me.Cells(x, 3).Value` to get your account number, which means you are going to write over your account numbers with "Yes" or "No".  (Unless, perhaps, `Me` and `ActiveSheet` are different?)

Comment: Where do you set values for ` my_url2` and `my_url4`?  If you navigate to a `vbNullString` the condition `Not IE.Busy And IE.readyState = 4` will never be true.